# getting error while mounting azure storage account with Databricks file system

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure Databricks and even to Spark technology. I am trying to mount my azure storage on HDFS using below method but it is giving error mentioned below. Can somebody please help me to fix this? In the notebook, I have selected Scala as a language.

```
    dbutils.fs.mount( source = "wasbs://rmwblobcontainer@rmwsa1.blob.core.windows.net/", mountPoint = "/mnt/mypath", extraConfigs = Map("fs.azure.account.key.rmwsa1.blob.core.windows.net" -> "{MX6BzXjcdIW+SJrvfocw8uFLT99Gs1aLtWBWkpQK7OyXIlctaoW1A/WQ9gBEGaxXcQ76FjEAI2hJGTiOQ6lCAA==}"))
```

**Error --**

```
    shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The String is not a valid Base64-encoded string
```

Comment: According to the error, you do not provide a valid storage access key. Could you please check it?

Comment: I have provided access key (key 1) of my storage account rmwsa1 and have tried this multiple times by regenerating access keys as well but it is giving me error. @jim

Comment: According to your code, you use "{}" to enclose your access key. Please remove "{}" and try again.

Comment: @RMW dont give out your secure access key in forums.. hoping you have changed some characters in that

Answer (score 0):

You will recieve this error message "`shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The String is not a valid Base64-encoded string`", when you have additional values in the Azure Storage access key.

Azure Storage access key contains curly braces "{}" at start & end, please do remove curly brackets and rerun the cell.

[image]